# Where can I find out more on Collatz-conjecture like sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, collatz-conjecture

I'm interested in [Collatz-conjecture (the 3n+1 problem)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) like sequences.  I'm interested in any literature that contains information about problems that are divided into similar cases.

I'm particularly interested in studies of sequences that have 3 or more cases, but information on 2 case problems is interesting as well.

I'm just trying to get a feel of what is known.  Anything will be helpful.

**So, where can we find lots of information on these types of problems/sequences?**

Comment: For what it is worth, the people who are able to answer this question necessarily know the Collatz conjecture - stating the Collatz problem just adds noise to your question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews:  I was afraid of that.  I guess I was trying to keep the question self-contained so that those that don't know could learn something too.  I've edited the question.

Comment: If this question is still up to date, check out the [7x±1 problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.00908).

Answer (score 7):

Anyone wanting to study the $3n+1$ problem and related sequences should check Jeffrey Lagarias' annotated bibliographies on the arXiv, posted [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608208) and [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309224). It contains some hundreds of papers, with for each paper a short summary of what it is about.

Comment: Lagarias has also published a *book* in which he collects several of the important papers on Collatz.

Answer (score 2):

A natural generalization of the Collatz problem is recursively undecidable.

You may be interested in [this paper](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~simon/RES/collatz.pdf).

Comment: A little irritated by the language in that articled. It says, "given a Collatz function $g$, it is undecidable...." Really, what they are saying is that the general problem, not the problem for any $g$, is undecidable, right? Seems sloppy. (There are problems in the $a_i,b_i$ definitions for the original Collatz problem, too, giving me the feeling this wasn't proof-read, much less reviewed...)

Comment: I agree with you. A good point.

Comment: My understanding is that there exists a particular Collatz-like problem for which the usual question is undecidable.

Comment: Yeah, that was my memory, too. I see the above linked article is actually a summary of a Conway article.

Comment: For that Conway article, it's from the American Mathematical Monthly and you can find it at [JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.120.03.192?uid=3738736&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21103290437813). I'd say that's more worthwhile reading than the "paper" linked in this answer (which is not finished, and contains several sloppy mistakes).

Answer (score 0):

[This arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.00908) deals with the $7x\pm1$ problem, having three (technically four) branches:

$$ f(n) = \begin{cases}
  7n+1 & \text{if $n\equiv+1\pmod{4}$,} \\
  7n-1 & \text{if $n\equiv-1\pmod{4}$,} \\
  n/2  & \text{if $n\equiv\phantom+0\pmod{2}$.} \\
\end{cases} $$

The conjecture is that the orbit of arbitrary positive integer
always returns to 1, exactly as in the case of $3x+1$ problem.